# Does the conduit for a wall oven need to be pulled inside the cabinet?

Tags: electrical, kitchens, oven

I just had the convection motor replaced on my double electric oven. I had our handyman, a very good one, do the job. In order to do so, he had to pull the oven out of the cabinet. No problem there. He changed out the motor and everything works fine.

This is what I am wondering about. In the installation manual, it shows how to pull the electrical conduit up on top of the oven (see pic). I watched the handyman and he did not do this when he was finished changing the motor. He just left the conduit hanging down. My question is, why does the conduit have to be curled up on top of the oven? Is it okay to just leave it hanging behind the oven? Thanks again for any replies.

[image]

Comment: Been there. No instructions to do this, as I recall, but necessary anyway. Even harder with a double-oven...

Comment: I would guess this is an answer to the problem of "the oven won't slide all the way in".

Comment: *a.* is only to help you achieve *d.* "you are sure the conduit is out of the way"

Answer (score 11):

Most likely is that the conduit hanging down the back takes up space, and depending on the cabinet you're installing the oven into there may not be enough space there to allow you to push the oven all the way in with the conduit in the way.

If your oven fits back into your cabinet the way it's supposed to, then you probably have that little extra space in the back for the conduit to hang there without interfering.

Comment: Or even worse: the oven smashes the conduit against the wall and breaks it (or shoves it through the wall). If the conduit gets caught on the back of the oven, you might not be able to pull the oven out again without damaging the wiring. If the conduit is laying on top, you can at least snake something in there and dislodge it.

Answer (score 6):

If it's flexible metal conduit as drawn in the diagram, then, depending on the exact position of the junction box and orientation of the L-fitting, the conduit might be crushed or split where it is forced over the top corner of the oven.

It seems from the diagram that the intent is to purposely position the junction box high enough and orient the fitting so that in the finished position the conduit makes a nice horizontal "S" shape in the space above the oven, and doesn't have to go through any tight corners.

I would remove the oven to make sure the conduit has not been damaged, and install it correctly.

I would hope the installer was sensitive enough to NOT force it, and hopefully the conduit did fit behind the oven without being damaged.  But I would check.

Comment: Is the metal whip considered to be conduit? (I know the install instructions *call* it conduit.)

Comment: Well, it (appears to be) made of FMC material and the instructions call it a conduit so I figured better to stick with it and focus on the question.